# Comparing find results in an active environment with transactions

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I’m looking to compare two find results from mongoDb since we are evaluating a different query structure that should yeild the same results.

I want to execute the queries to run in parallel with the same start time, and then compare that the results are an exact match.

The system is very active and documents are updated and deleted very often.

Does it make sense to execute the two finds in a transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense. In your case, you need to block phantom reads, that are guaranteed not to occur in a MongoDB transaction, whose isolation level is snapshot. This is a test I run in Nodejs, that you can find [here](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/blob/main/test/transaction.test.js#L266):

```
test('Newly inserted rows are invisible, no phantom reads', async () => {
        await transactionWithCustomOptions({}, async (client, session, db) => {
        const beforeInsertUsers = await db.collection(ACCOUNT_COLL).countDocuments({}, { session });

        await accountRepository.insertAccount("test3", 2000);
        const afterInsertUsers = await db.collection(ACCOUNT_COLL).countDocuments({}, { session });

        expect(beforeInsertUsers).toEqual(afterInsertUsers);
    });
});
```

This test asserts that transactional operations are completely isolated from outside operations. For the theoretical part, I wrote a [report](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc) about MongoDB transactions: you might be interested in the paragraphs *WiredTiger cache* and *Snapshot isolation*.